# Keep android progress bar or resume it

Tags: java, android-studio, android-progressbar, countdowntimer

I would like to know how to keep the state of my progressbar or resume where it left off.  Let me explain, it's a timer with a progress bar,  when the user close the activity or close the activity, the timer is started as a background service (the timer works correctly), I would like that when the user close the activity or close the application, and  when he returns, the progress bar will resume where it was.  for now what happens is when it returns to the timer, the progress bar returns to zero.  here is my code of my adapter where Lessons and Timer service takes place

This how I save progress bar state

```
private static SharedPreferences.Editor pref;
private static int saveProgressBarState;
private static SharedPreferences getProgressBarState;

private CountDownTimer countDown(final long time, final ProgressBar lessonProgress, long originalTimerSize) {

        final int timerLengthInSecond = (int) time / 1_000;

        lessonProgress.setMax((int) originalTimerSize / 1_000);

        return new CountDownTimer(time, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long l) {

                long secondRemaining = l / 1_000;

                lessonProgress.setProgress((int) (timerLengthInSecond - secondRemaining));

                //Getting progress of progress bar
                saveProgressBarState = lessonProgress.getProgress();

            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {

                lessonProgress.setProgress(timerLengthInSecond);
            }
        };

    }

//this method is called when onPause() is called on the activity
public static void runLessonTimerInBackground(Context context) {

        pref = context.getSharedPreferences("LESSONPROGRESS", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        pref.putInt("savedprogress", progressBarStateSave);
        pref.apply();

    }
```

I want to get saved progressbarstate and resume progress where it was and continue progress

Comment: Save progressBar position in [sharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences), get the position on `onResume()` and set it

Comment: @RahulGaur i save timer progressbar state with the method getProgress() in sharedPreferences, how to resume it and continue progress ?

Comment: @RahulGaur i edited please check

Comment: @RahulGaur There is still nothing in onResume () it is this party which I cannot manage to make.  I ask for help to be able to do this part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add these links in your `onResume()` I m assuming you can tweak and apply this in your real-progress of the `lesson`

```
int lastProgress = pref.getInt("savedprogress", 0); //0 is default value

lessonProgress.setProgress(lastProgress); //this will set the progress

//here you might also need to do some other stuff related to your code and req
//you can also resume your lesson video from here, etc.
```

If you want to save multiple lesson progress in sharePref, I suggest you to save progress like

```
String progressPrefName = "savedProgress_" + lessonID; //here lessonID is lesson's unique ID
pref.putInt(progressPrefName, progressBarStateSave); // here pass the name which can be "savedProgress_1" referring to lesson with ID 1
```

You can then get it like

```
String progressPrefName = "savedProgress_" + lessonID; 

int lastProgress = pref.getInt(progressPrefName, 0); //0 is default value

lessonProgress.setProgress(lastProgress); //this will set the progress
```